# My button "close" don't close but hide the page

Tags: java, android, button, return, forceclose

**Hello all,** My button (close) in the closeListener (in my java code). When I push this button (close) I go back correctly in my first page but it don't close correctly my Rent page (second page), my second page remain open below my first page (hide behind the first page), how can I do for close correctly the second page (Rent) ?

```
package albencreation.realestateapplication;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Rent extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText price = null;
    EditText profit = null;
    TextView result = null;
    Button envoyer = null;
    Button close = null;
    Button info = null;
    Button clear = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.rent);

        price = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.price);
        profit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.profit);
        result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result);
        envoyer = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttcalculate);
        close = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttclose);
        info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttinfo);
        clear = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttclear);

        envoyer.setOnClickListener(envoyerListener);
        close.setOnClickListener(closeListener);
        info.setOnClickListener(infoListener);
        clear.setOnClickListener(clearListener);
    }

    private OnClickListener envoyerListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String p = price.getText().toString();
            String o = profit.getText().toString();

            float pValue;
            if (p.isEmpty()) {
                pValue = 0;
            } else {
                pValue = Float.valueOf(p);
            }
            float oValue;
            if (o.isEmpty()) {
                oValue = 0;
            } else {
                oValue = Float.valueOf(o);
            }

            float resultat = oValue * pValue / 100;
            result.setText("the rent is " + String.valueOf(resultat) + " currency");
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener closeListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent jumpage = new Intent(Rent.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(jumpage);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener infoListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent jumpage = new Intent(Rent.this, Inforent.class);
            startActivity(jumpage);
        }
    };

    private OnClickListener clearListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            price.getText().clear();
            profit.getText().clear();
            String defaut = "result rent";
            result.setText(defaut);
        }
    };

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call the `finish(`) method to finish your activity for good:

```
private OnClickListener closeListener = new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent jumpage = new Intent(Rent.this, MainActivity.class);
            startActivity(jumpage);
            Rent.this.finish();
        }
    };
```

Comment: I posted this question, title : How to put a number decimal (###,###,###.00) in a string value.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this

```
 private OnClickListener closeListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent jumpage = new Intent(Rent.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(jumpage);
    }
};
```

Just write as below

```
 private OnClickListener closeListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       this.finish();
    }
};
```

Comment: in this case, this is not a valid context because it a anonymous inner class.

Comment: You are inside an anonymous inner class, this is not a context.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :-)

Comment: When you are moving from one Activity to second....
First activity is already put in activity_stack therefore,
by finishing second activity (instead starting first activity), you will be navigated to first one only.
This is known as optimised code. 
Thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Just call `finish()` to close `Rent` activity.

**Try this:**

```
private OnClickListener closeListener = new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent jumpage = new Intent(Rent.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(jumpage);

        finish();

    }
};
```